# Atualizar Datatable - Ajax cellEdit (Primefaces )

Tags: ajax, primefaces

Olá,
Estou tentando atualizar a DataTable mas não estou conseguindo. Segue o código:

```
<h:form id="testeForm" >
 <p:panel toggleable="true" id="panelTeste">                
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="1" id="panelGridTeste">

       <p:dataTable  id="dataTableTeste" var="teste" value="#{testeController.listaTeste" editable="true" editMode="cell" >

          <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{testeController.atualizarDataTable}"  update=":testeForm:dataTableTeste"/>

          <p:columnGroup type="header">
             <p:row>
                <p:column headerText="Col1" />
                <p:column headerText="Col2" />
                <p:column headerText="Col3" />
             </p:row>
          </p:columnGroup>

          <p:column>
             <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{teste.valorCol1}" /></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{teste.valorCol1}" /></f:facet>
             </p:cellEditor>
          </p:column>

          <p:column>
             <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{teste.valorCol2}" /></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{teste.valorCol2}" /></f:facet>
             </p:cellEditor>
          </p:column>

          <p:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{teste.valorCol3}" />
          </p:column>
       </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>
 </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

**testeController:**

```
public void atualizarDataTable(CellEditEvent event) {           
    for (Teste teste : listaTeste) {
       valorCol3 = valorCol1 + valorCol2;
    }
}
```

Tudo funciona corretamente, só não consigo atualizar as informações da DataTable.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Já tentei também com o `p:remoteCommand` e funciona se após eu editar a cell apertar **enter** mas não funcionar se sair do campo com a tecla **tab** (que é o que eu preciso).

Estou tentando atualizar na **Controller/Bean** com `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("testeForm:dataTableTeste");` e também não está dando certo... Não atualiza.

Obrigado

Comment: Alguém? Acredito que não tem como fazer da forma que estou precisando. Será que com `p:hotkey`???

Comment: Você realmente precisar colocar esse caminho no  `update=":testeForm:dataTableTeste"` ? E da onde vem as variáveis do método `atualizarDataTable()`? Pelo que vejo não atualizou porque ele não processou sua tabela ainda. tente colocar um `process="@this" `no ajax.

Comment: Eu geralmente coloco um `p:ajax` em cada input. `<p:inputText value="#{teste.valorCol1}" > <p:ajax event="change" process "@this" update="testeForm:dataTableTeste"/></p:inputText >`. Com isso a cada vez que você editar um valor na sua tabela ele ira processa-la e atualizar.